# PHP Array of Objects with arrays inside. Merge these

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array of Objects. These Objects have different keys with arrays as value. As an output I need a combined array of all these Array.
Example:

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    datas: [a,b,c]
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    datas: [d,e,f]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    datas: [f,g,h]
  }
]
```

As output I need:
`[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`
I couldnt find an easy one liner so far. I could iterate over the Array and merging all arrays in a new one. But yeah, I like one liner and as far as I know PHP there is a quick way for that

Comment: are you asking for a pythonic one liner in PHP?

Comment: Under the hood, any one liner would do the exact same thing your algorithm does - iterate and merge all these arrays together. Any specific reason why you insist on a one liner? You say "quick way", but I don't know what that represents for you - code that executes faster or just something that requires less typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your oneliner is:

```
print_r(array_merge(...array_column($array, 'datas')));
```

Working [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/8Y0VT).

Answer (score -1):

Use this function array_push();